# Squirrel SQL Disconnects when Incorrect SQL executed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, squirrel-sql

Squirrel 3.6 connected to Oracle 11g using an Oracle thin driver (ojdbc6.jar).

Whenever I type an SQL query incorrectly, instead of saying 'Wrong SQL' (or something to that effect), I get an Oralce Error (Error: IO Error Size Data Mismatch) and Squirrel disconnects. I then need to reconnect Squirrel which takes quite a while.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded the latest OJDBC file and it worked fine.